# Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch3

Tags: matlab

I have about 2400 files (some of them are tsv, others are .txt). I am told that they were 72x144 (but I did not check them all). when i run this script :

```
load area.mat    %Area Calculation %

%area= transpose(area);

area= repmat(area,1,144); % replicating the vector area 144 times

files= dir('200*');  % loading files of June
for m=1:length(files)
June(:,:,m)= dlmread(files(m).name); % loading files in a 3 dimensional  %matrix
end


June(June<0)= NaN; % replacing outliers by Not a Number NaN
outliers = isnan(June); % detect NaNs

t= 1:numel(June);   % creating a variable t which take values from 1 to number %of elements of matrix June

June(outliers) = interp1(t(~outliers), June(~outliers),    t(outliers),'nearest'); % interpolating NaNs by nearest values
z= mean(June,3); % obtaining a matrix June that consists of averages of same cells

June_temp= z.*area; % weighing temperatures by fractions of areas ???????
June_AvgTemp= sum(June_temp(:));
fprintf('The average temperature of June is %0.4f Kelvins, %0.4f degrees Celsius\n',June_AvgTemp,June_AvgTemp-273.15)
```

I get the error:

Subscripted assignment dimension mismatch.

Error in almost_F_script (line 16)
June(:,:,m)= dlmread(files(m).name); % loading files in a 3 dimensional matrix

I would really appreciate your help!! thank you

Comment: You have a file that isn't 72 x 144.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. i Thought that must be the problem, because when my loop gets to m= 969 it gives me that error message. I don't think that it will be the only file because I have about 12000 files and that is only for one year. I will get more files because I need 10 years of files. So is there a way to insert another script inside that loop, so that whenever a file that does not have a 72x144 dimension, it will interpolate the missing values?  meanwhile how can I get the name of the file that has an issue please? in this case the corresponding m is 969. Thank you for helping me!

Comment: I would just call `dbstop if error` before running your script and then it will place a debug prompt right where the error occurs and you can investigate which file is causing the issue and why

Answer (score -1):

The problem was due to the fact that I was using .TVS files that were 72x144, and .txt files that were 1x10368 as my dataset. I just converted the same data as .txt files, then I reshaped the outcome of the loop which is  June to 72x144 and everything worked fine. Thank you for the help anyway!